# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it prob in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have created a class library called AddServiceLibrary  in which I have a method called 
AssemblyLoader the code is below:

```
string executingAssemblyName =  Application.ExecutablePath;
        AssemblyName asmName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(executingAssemblyName);
        AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        Assembly assembly = appDomain.Load(asmName);
        _assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes().ToList();            
        LoadAppConfig();
```

this method loads the executing assembly in the current appdomain.
I have another method called LoadAppConfig()

```
ServicesSection  serviceSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/services") as ServicesSection;

            ServiceElementCollection sereleColl = serviceSection.Services;


            string endPointAddress = string.Empty ;
            foreach (var ele in sereleColl)
            {
               _serviceType = GetServiceType((System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceElement)(ele)).Name);

               break;

            }

            ServiceHoster.HostService(_serviceType);
```

This method reads the app.config file and finds the type of wcf service .
I have one more class ServiceHoster in which I have a method HostService :

```
public static void HostService(Type serviceType)
        {

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType))
            {
                host.Open();
            }

        }
```

now , I have a different project called MyWCFService and I add the reference of AddServiceLibrary in this project and call the method;

```
AddServiceLibrary.LoadLibrary lb = new AddServiceLibrary.LoadLibrary();
            lb.AssemblyLoader();
```

I hope at this point that my service is hosted properly , but when i want AddServiceReference in my client project it tell's me that 
**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it  prob in** 
While if I don't use my AddServiceLibrary , it's finding the service and working fine.
Please any one have a look on it and suggest me what could be wrong in my approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are disposing the ServiceHost instance as soon as you open it. Remove the using block, and handle disposal of this host separately.

Your design decision to have a static ServiceHoster is probably an issue here. Whatever is hosting the service by instantiating the ServiceHost instance needs to manage the life of this instance and its disposal.

Comment: thank you sir , it works when i remove the using block , but sir can you pls guide me how can I implement the disposal of service host separately ?

Comment: What method do you currently have in place to stop the hosting of the service? Can you post more of your ServiceHoster class?

Comment: The complete class is as follows:
class ServiceHoster
    {
        public static void HostService(Type serviceType)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
            try
            {
                host.Open();
            } 
        }
    }

Comment: You don't seem to have considered shutting down these services anywhere. When you instantiate your LoadLibrary, how long does that object live for?

Comment: I instantiate LoadLibrary object and call the AddServiceLibrary method of it , from this methos I call ServiceHoster.HostService method , I am sorry but i don't know how long does it live ?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain the broader context of what you are trying to do as well I could make some suggestions as to how you would need to modify your approach?

Comment: Your ServiceHost object will fall out of scope once your constructor completes execution.  You need to keep it alive longer.  These are basic C# / OO concepts you'll need to learn to be successful.  More on object lifetime here: http://darkcodingzone.blogspot.com/2008/11/basics-of-object-lifetime-in-cnet.html

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I had been looking at my code for ages before I read this! +1